# How to create a dictionary with dynamic key and value pair in angular 12

Tags: angular, dictionary

I like to create a dictionary object in angular as the code below.
Since key is a dynamic with id, how can I make this work?

```
 private createCartItem(id: number, quantity: number) {
    var keya =  'addtocart_' + id + '.EnteredQuantity';
    const dictionary = { '${keya}' : quantity };
    return dictionary;
}
```

This key/value pair object will be a body of http post to web api call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by using the computed property syntax in the object literal to make a dynamic key:

```
private createCartItem(id: number, quantity: number) {
     const key =  'addtocart_' + id + '.EnteredQuantity';
     const dictionary = { [key]: quantity };
     return dictionary;
}
```